# Check the input checkbox in a specific H3 text with Selenium Webdriver and Java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I want to check the input checkbox with selenium webdriver and Java,  I am trying to click a checkbox inside a third heading (h3) input element of the page:-

example of the element is:-

```
<h3 class="header-element">
   <input type="checkbox" checked=""/>
   I want to click the checkbox for this particular text
</h3>
<h3 class="header-element">
   <input type="checkbox" checked=""/>
   I dont want to click the checkbox for this text
</h3>
```

I have tried the following method

```
//h3[starts-with(text(),'I want to click')]/input
```

and

```
//h3[text()='I want to click the checkbox for this particular text']/input
```

None of these seems to work. Can you please suggest another possible method of doing this. Thanks.

Comment: please explain your question,the data is insufficient or confusing

Comment: I like it when developers put a listener on the checkbox label so that if I click the label, it toggles the checkbox, then I can click on it a few different ways with selenium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The xpaths used in the question wont work,because `input` come first then comes the `text`.

You can use the position of h3 element to `check` the correct option.

**for example** if both the h3 elements are within a div, the following xpath would work.

```
//div[@id='divs_id']/h3[@class='header-element'][1]/input
```

The above xpath will click on first checkbox.
similarly use the following xpath to click on second checkbox,

```
//div[@id='divs_id']/h3[@class='header-element'][2]/input
```

Comment: wont work when you want to click a specific checkbox in a list of 100 h3 elements for example. The answer from Paul works.

Answer (score 3):

Try using `normalize-space()`:

```
//h3[normalize-space(.)='I want to click the checkbox for this particular text']
    /input
```

or

```
//h3[starts-with(normalize-space(.))='I want to click']/input
```

See http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-normalize-space

Comment: Thanks Paul, normalize-space() fixed it

Answer (score 0):

[check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZPZ3J/)

is it something like this

```
<h3 class="header-element">
   <input type="checkbox" checked=""/>
   I want to click the checkbox for this particular text
</h3>

<h3 class="header-element">
   <input type="checkbox" />
   I dont want to click the checkbox for this text
</h3>
```

Comment: I mean searching for the checkbox using webdriver and xpath